# indexpath.row is showing less number of rows

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created an `tableview` with an array. There are 7 items in my array. But in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i'm unable to get `indexpath.row == 6`. What could be the reason.
Code is below for this.

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home",@"ansCategory",@"askQue",@"myQue",@"likedQue", @"topQue", @"topUser",nil];             
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
       // Return the number of sections.
       return 1;
     }

      -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        // NSLog(@"count::::::%d",self.menu.count);
           return self.menu.count;
     }
       -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        NSLog(@"rows:%@",indexPath);
        NSLog(@"row:%@",[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }
    return cell;

 }
```

I'm getting following out put:

[here] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz6t34xr7l4glxz/menu1.png)

first index is overlaying on last one.

Comment: What does NSLog show?

Comment: maximum 6 cells are shown at a time on screen. scroll table to get 7th row.

Comment: NSLog is showing row index upto 5 only, though i have 7 count in (menu.count).

i have scrolled table but its not showing indexpath.row == 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my code to following line and it worked.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

The cell is reused.
Put your log statement outside of the `if(cell=nil)`:

Here is the working example for outputting the contents of the array in a tableview. Item with index 6 which is the seventh in the array ("topUser") is in red.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"rows:%@",indexPath);
    NSLog(@"row:%@",[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text = self.menu[indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row == 6)
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];        
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes its working then, but what if i want to customize cell at indexpath.row == 6 ?????

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Thats true friend, thought the problem is that i am initializing my cells form array inside "if(cell=nil)".

So label for indexpath.row == 0 is also showing up on cell of indexpath.row == 6 ; if i write 

 "if (indexPath.row == 6) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"This is number 7";
    }"
  outside of "if(cell=nil)".

Comment: i want to initialize menu view having same number of cells as in array of menu.

but problem is that in "if(cell = nil)" i am not getting indexpath.row==6 ; even i have 7 elements in array.

Same thing i have did many times ago for another development and it worked very fine.

I couldn't understand why i'm not getting indexpath.row = 7 at there.

Comment: in an array with seven entries, you'll never get index 7 because it starts with 0 and ends with 6.
I just copied my example over in a controller and it gives me a table view with your menu items from "Home" to "topUser", which are 7 items :)

Comment: sry for mistake, i know that i can't get 7 index. But i should get 6 atleast which i'm not getting in "if(cell = nil)" . I have updated my question with your suggestion. See the output.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: within "if(cell == nil)" you won't get all the indexes, because the cell is reused. iOS will give you a cell back in the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier". You don't want to have any row specific logic within the "if(cell == nil)" for that reason.

Comment: I have been getting all indexes in "if(cell == nil)" . And again with my updated code I got them all :)

Answer (score 3):

For N items the last indexpath is (N-1)

Thus, if you have 10 items, then the index path of last item is 9 because the indexpath of 1st item in array is 0.

indexPath of items starts with 0 and not 1.

Try to access the index path in your answer like below in your code

Instead of :

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        NSLog(@"rows:%@",indexPath);
        NSLog(@"row:%@",[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }
```

Write

```
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }
    //Access the indexPath outside here... 
    //Because once the cells are created and not nil 
    //then the above scope will be bypassed.
    NSLog(@"rows:%@",indexPath);
    NSLog(@"row:%@",[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

Comment: That is not the problem here .The question clearly says has 7 rows and  the asker cannot achieve 6th

Answer (score 2):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

gets executed whenever the new row is needed to be created and added to the tableview.The tableview populates row such that when it needs to be dispayed on screen it is created by calling the very same method.So If your 7 th row is not visible on screen the method wont get executed for row 7 ie indexpath.row 6 and so to get the method to log the 7 th row just scroll down so that that cell can be made visible by the table and it will execute the method and you can have the log